# varying combination of columns in data.table where clause

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with 1000+ binary columns, but a simple example is:

```
dt <- data.table(one=c(1,1,0), two=c(0,0,1), three=c(1,1,0), four=c(1,1,1))
```

I want to count the number of times each combination of a predefined number of columns all are equal to 1. So for example if I wanted to count the "1" matches between every 2 columns, I could do:

```
a <- combn(names(dt),2)[1,]
b <- combn(names(dt),2)[2,]

for(i in 1:length(a)){
print(c(a[i], b[i], dt[get(a[i])==1 & get(b[i])==1,.N]))
}
```

I want to vary the number of columns that are combined and I need an efficient way to do this.

I can solve that with `eval(parse())` like this:

```
n <- 3 # number of columns to combine

for(i in 1:n){assign(paste0("a", i), combn(names(dt),n)[i,])}

for(i in 1:length(a1)){
  expr1 <- paste0("c(",paste0(rep("a", n), 1:n, "[i]", collapse=","), ")")
  expr2 <- paste0("dt[",paste0("get(",rep("a", n), 1:n, ")", sep=" ==TRUE ", collapse = " & "),",.N]")

  print(c(eval(parse(text=expr1)),  eval(parse(text=expr2))))
}
```

Nevertheless, a microbenchmarking test on the simple code above shows that `get()` is about 5 times faster than `eval(parse())`.

What is an efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the indicated `all1` as a function in `combn`:

```
k <- 3
DF <- as.data.frame(dt)
all1 <- combn(names(DF), k, function(x) sum(apply(DF[, x] == 1, 1, all)))
data.frame(t(combn(names(DF), k)), all1)
```

giving:

```
   X1    X2    X3 all1
1 one   two three    0
2 one   two  four    0
3 one three  four    2
4 two three  four    0
```

Comment: The solution you gave few minutes ago with the DF was working correctly and was faster :) The current one does not give correct results.

Comment: OK. Have reverted to earlier solution.

Comment: Awesome! This solution is about 400 microseconds faster than the sapply!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea,

```
sapply(combn(dt, 3, simplify = FALSE), function(i){
                v1 <- sum(rowSums(i) == ncol(i));
                setNames(v1, paste(names(i), collapse = '-'))
               })

# one-two-three   one-two-four one-three-four two-three-four 
#             0              0              2              0
```

Comment: Neat, that's about 10x faster than my solution!